# Angular JS: How do I set a property on directive local scope that i can use in the template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I want to access a variable in this case map in the directive without having to predefine it like setting it as an attr of the directrive map="someValue". And also i dont want to use scope.$apply because i actually only want the variable in the isolated scope of the directive. Is this even possible ?
What is the best practice here? Basically my directive needs to do both. Access the parent scope and have its own scope which with i can build the template with.

Thank you everybody.

Here my Js code:

```
.directive('myFilter', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            source: '=source',
            key: '=key',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('dataLoaded', function(e) { 
                scope.map = {};
                angular.forEach(scope.source, function(paramObj) {
                    if (!scope.map[paramObj[scope.key]]) {
                        var newEntry = {
                            value: paramObj[scope.key],
                            isChecked: false
                        }
                        scope.map[paramObj[scope.key]] = newEntry;
                    }
                });
            }); 
        }   
    }
});
```

and my html:

```
<my-filter source="metaPara.filteredParameters" key="'value'">
    <table class="table table-borered">
       <tr data-ng-repeat="item in map">
          <td>{{item.value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</my-filter>
```

Comment: If you use =key or whatever, it two-way binds to your controller scope variable. If you use &key, it does not. Is that what you need to do?

Comment: Instead of 'link' try giving the directive a controller; then you should be able to create a $scope variable in the controller that is available to the template, but is not exposed to someone using the directive (I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to refer to the Angular documentation for directives, again.

If you want an isolate-scope (a scope which has ***no access to ancestors***), then use

```
scope : { /* ... */ }
```

otherwise, if you want a unique scope, which does have access to ancestors, use

```
scope : true
```

Then, you can put your HTML-modifying or event-listening (that doesn't rely on ng-click or something else Angular already covers) in

```
link : function (scope, el, attrs, controller) { }
```

...and you can put all of your regular implementation inside of

```
controller   : ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    var myController = this;
    myController.property = "12";
}],
controllerAs : "myController"
```

So that in your template you can say:

```
<span>{{ myController.property }}</span>
```

You can also use a pre-registered controller, which you call by name:

```
controller   : "mySimpleController",
controllerAs : "myController"
```

Also, rather than using `$scope.$apply`, I'd recommend using `$timeout` (has to be injected).

The difference is that `$scope.$apply` will only work at certain points -- if you're already inside of a digest cycle, it will throw an error, and not update anything.
`$timeout( )` sets the updates to happen during the ***next*** update-cycle.

Ideally, you should know whether or not you need an `$apply` or not, and be able to guarantee that you're only using it in one spot, per update/digest, but `$timeout` will save you from those points where you aren't necessarily sure.

Comment: Thank you. This is pretty much what i was looking for.